# How can I mount component by using react hooks?

Tags: reactjs

```
 const handleDisplays = () => {
        if (window.scrollY > 0) {
            setNavbar(true)
        } else {
            setNavbar(false)
        }

        if (window.scrollY > 1000) {
            setHelpDisplay(true)
        } else {
            setHelpDisplay(false)
        }

        if (window.scrollY > 1400) {
            setContactDisplay(true)
        } else {
            setContactDisplay(false)
        }

    }

    useEffect(() => {
        window.addEventListener('scroll', handleDisplays)
    }, [])
```

I have this method to set kinda animations when scrolling in the home page of website. It works properly but when I go any other component and scroll the page, it throws this error:

> Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.

Website doesn't crash but it's annoying.

I tried to write it without using useEffect and also tried:

```
useEffect(() => {
        return  () => {
            window.addEventListener('scroll', handleDisplays)
        } 
}, [])
```

But I couldn't handle it.

How can I get rid of this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add removeEventListener on unmount.

```
useEffect(() => {
        window.addEventListener('scroll', handleDisplays)
        return  () => {
            window.removeEventListener('scroll', handleDisplays, true)
        } 
}, [])
```

this blog explains how you can add or remove event listeners in [useEffect](https://newbedev.com/how-do-i-window-removeeventlistener-using-react-useeffect)